# Displaying data from a specific date php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to display data from a specific date, for example, total income for a day, or total income for a week and so on.

I have no idea how to do it, I have only created a query that would display a total, but i also need it to display specific dates. as i've said above.

the data type in my database table is TIMESTAMP, with a format like 2014-08-28 04:08:23.

Here is my query.

```
$qry = "SELECT sum(order_detail.quantity*order_detail.price) as chenes, orders.date 
        FROM order_detail 
        LEFT JOIN orders 
        ON order_detail.orderid=orders.serial";
```

I know i would use WHERE clause but after that, i have no idea what to do next. Please help me Thank you.

Comment: where orders .date between 'yyyy-mm-dd H:i:s' AND 'yyyy-mm-dd H:i:s'

Comment: what about just the date, the time is not important as of now when getting daily reports. @Undefined_variable

Comment: use date(orders.date) between 'yyyy-mm-dd' And 'yyyy-mm-dd'

Comment: Use a `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: @Undefined_variable It does not work. :(

Comment: for one record per date you must use group by date(orders.date) as suggested by hjpotter92

Answer (score 1):

You can express the query as:

```
SELECT sum(od.quantity*od.price) as chenes, o.date 
FROM order_detail od JOIN
     orders o
ON od.orderid = o.serial
WHERE date(o.date) = YOURDATEHERE
```

However, this format makes it difficult for MySQL to use an index on the `date` column.  A better representation is:

```
SELECT sum(od.quantity*od.price) as chenes, o.date 
FROM order_detail od JOIN
     orders o
ON od.orderid = o.serial
WHERE o.date >= YOURDATEHERE and o.date < YOURDATEHERE + interval 1 day;
```

This would allow MySQL to take advantage of an index on `date`.

Note that I changed the `left join` to a `join`.  You would have a bad database design if `order_detail` records did not have valid links to the `order` table.  In addition, you want to filter on the *second* table, which would turn the outer join into an inner join anyway.